# How to efficiently store and search a non-uniform grid for 2D space using python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have to store non-uniform 2D grids as shown in the following figures. The corners of each cell are known. Eventually, given a point (x,y), I have to return the cell that contains it. How to store the corners of each cell in Python to enable a fast lookup?

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: How big are these grids? How are they stored? Are there many of these grids or can you manually define a mathematical function that will determine this for you?

Comment: You could sub-divide the grid into uniformly-sized, but smaller  rectangles. This could be repeated recursively to form a hierarchy of them, Once that is created, finding the cel thatl corresponding to an (x, y) point would be relatively fast because it would allow large numbers of candidates in sub-division to be quickly rejected.

Comment: Storing a rectangle generally reduces to needed 4 value. You might be able to save some storage space by storing say, the upper-left corner in as say 4-byte values (integer or float), and storing the width and height as two 2-byte values. Since the rectangles all lie on a grid, you might be able to just store the delta value between each of their corners. Note though that any compression of the data will likely slow down retrieving their values for doing computations — so likely a trade-off will need to be made.

Comment: Don't store the points at all, instead, store the lines - the coefficients that is. You would have to derive them anyway to determine if you are within the shape (at least for your example on the right.) There is a whole lot more optimization you can do from there, of course. You may also want to store the endpoints of your line, which will make narrowing in on your position faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Storing the coefficients of the lines addresses both the grid types and also should make the search easier. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I stored a list of pairs of coordinates that define each line, such as:

`gridhlines = [[(322.162, 0), (877.838, 0)], [(322.162, 352.432), (877.838, 352.432)], [(322.162, 406.486), (910.27, 406.486)], [(332.541, 454.054), (966.486, 454.054)], [(322.162, 516.757), (877.838, 508.108)], [(321.162, 562.162), (877.838, 560)], [(322.162, 607.568), (877.838, 611.892)], [(402.162, 735.135), (715.676, 735.135)], [(332.160, 960), (332.160, 960)]]`

and computed 
    `d = (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (y - y1) * (x2 - x1)` 
in an iterative manner for the gridhlines. Here, the grid line AB is given by points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` and for a given point P`(x, y)`,  I then used the fact that if `d < 0` the point P`(x, y)` lies on one side of the line, otherwise, if `d > 0`, it lies on the other side, from the following answer to exactly determine the horizontal and vertical lines containing P`(x, y)`:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274712/calculate-on-which-side-of-a-straight-line-is-a-given-point-located

Answer (score 1):

A grid can represented by a named tuple (also by a tuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Create two named tuples - for grid and a point
Grid = namedtuple('Grid', ['x', 'y', 'width', 'height'])
# Alternatively you can use other ways, like lower left x, lower left y etc. 
# For the case when you deal with directed / transformed grid, you can define
# a list of metadata Grid = namedtuple('Grid', ['x', 'y', 'meta'])

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

grid = Grid(x=0, y=0, height=10, width=10)
# for list of metadata something like   grid = Grid(x=0, y=0, meta=['some_meta'])
```

Then, an adjacent grid on the right, for example would be

```
grid_right = Grid(x=10, y=0, height=10, width=5)
```

The benefit of named tuple would be using object properties rather than tuple indexes.

Then, if you have a list of grids and a point to check:

```
grids = [grid1, grid2, grid3, grid4,]
point_to_check = Point(x=1.2, y=1.3)
```

The check would be something like:

```
found = False

for p in points:
    if point_to_check.x >= p.x and point_to_check.x <= p.x + p.width:
        if point_to_check.y >=p.y and point_to_check.y <= p.y + p.height
            found = True
```

Tuples are immutable and this gives you some efficiency when working with large number of points. Same effect can be reached with regular tuples, but then you
have to use indexes rather than properties.

Comment: Height and width may or may not be a constant for a cell. But this will work for the example grid on the left. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. It can be adjusted to suite your needs - tuples may include lists in them, if needed.

Comment: For directed grid on the right you can define different types of metadata in a list (edges, corners, angles etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you can be certain that the grid is rectilinear. All you need are two lists: One containing the X-values, and another for the Y-values.
Eg.

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|1| 2 | 3 | Each grid is labelled with its number. 
|_|_ _|_ _| Note, each underscore corresponds to a width of 1.
|4| 5 | 6 |
|_|_ _|_ _| For this grid, `X = [0, 1, 3, 5]` and `Y = [0, 2, 4]`
```

Given a point `(a, b)`, all we need is to get the index for the largest element in `X` which `a` is less than.
Same goes for `Y`.

```
import pandas as pd

num_cols = len(X)

Columns = pd.series(X)
Rows = pd.series(Y)

col = Columns.searchsorted(a)
row = Rows.searchsorted(b)

cell_number = col + row * num_cols
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. The grid may not be rectilinear for some cases.